# How to bubble sort in descending order (HIGHEST to Lowest) Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

My bubble sort only work on the highest number located on the second column of the table under Maggie. And it doesn't follow through the whole array. What is not working in my code? I looked at different bubble sort code and it looks similar to mine.

```js
function main() {

  var myArr = new Array(
      ["Robert Hill", 123.54], 
      ["Christopher Reddkin", 54.67],
      ["Maggie Woods", 1000.87],
      ["Jennifer Jones", 3.34],
      ["Marcus Parker", 64.98]);
  original(myArr);
  bubbleSort(myArr);
}

function original(myarray) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    myarray[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      myarray[i][j];
    }
  }
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

  for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
      col.innerText = myarray[i][j];
    }
  }
  console.log(myarray);
  return myarray;
}

function bubbleSort(myarr) {

  var lengths = myarr.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < lengths; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < (lengths - i - 1); j++) {
      if (myarr[i] > myarr[j + 1]) {
        var tmp = myarr[j];
        myarr[j] = myarr[j + 1];
        myarr[j + 1] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }
  var table2 = document.getElementById("myTable2");

  for (var i = 0, row; row = table2.rows[i]; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
      col.innerText = myarr[i][j];
    }
  }
  console.log(myarr);
  return myarr;
}

main();
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid black; }
table { margin: 1em; border-collapse: collapse; }
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>

<table id="myTable2">
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `if (myarr[i] ...` -> `if (myarr[j] ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your logic a bit. Simply swapped the array cells if the next one is bigger.

```
     function bubbleSort(myarr) {

      var lengths = myarr.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < lengths; i++) {
          for (var j = i+1; j < (lengths); j++) {
            if (myarr[j][1] > myarr[i][1]) {
                var tmp = myarr[i];
                myarr[i] = myarr[j];
                myarr[j] = tmp;   
            }
          }
          console.log(myarr);
          console.log("-------------------");
      }  



      var table2 = document.getElementById("myTable2");

      for (var i = 0, row; row = table2.rows[i]; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
          col.innerText = myarr[i][j];
        }
      }
      console.log(myarr);
      return myarr;
    }
```